# $O_{\pi}(G/N) = O_{\pi'}(G/N) = 1$ in $\pi$-separable group implies $G = N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\pi$ be a set of primes, set $\pi' := \mathbb P \setminus \pi$. A finite group $G$ is called a $\pi$-group if the prime divisors of its order are contained in $\pi$. Denote by $O_{\pi}(G)$ the largest $\pi$-group in $G$ which is normal. Then a group $G$ is called $\pi$-closed if $G / O_{\pi}(G)$ is a $\pi'$-group. Equivalently if we denote by $O^{\pi}(G)$ the smallest normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is a $\pi$-group, then a group $G$ is $\pi$-closed if
$$
 O_{\pi}(G) = O^{\pi'}(G).
$$
A group $G$ is called $\pi$-separable, if for every $U \le G$, $U \ne 1$ there exists some $N \unlhd U, N \ne U$ such that
$$
 U / N
$$
is $\pi$-closed, i.e. every nontrivial subgroup has a nontrivial $\pi$-closed factor group. There is also a characterisation in terms of [subgroup series](http://planetmath.org/piseparablegroup).

> Now let $G$ be $\pi$-separable and $N \unlhd G$, why does $O_{\pi}(G / N) = O_{\pi'}(G / N) = 1$ implies $G = N$?

Comment: I prefer the definition using subgroups series. From that, it is clear that $G$ $\pi$-separable implies $G/N$ is $\pi$-separable.

Comment: I see, this has not that much to do with the factor group construction, but is a property of $\pi$-separable groups themselves. If $G \ne 1$ and $G$ is $\pi$-separable, then at least one of the groups $O_{\pi}(G)$ or $O_{\pi'}(G)$ is non-trivial. For if $1 = A_0 < A_1 < \ldots A_{n-1} < A_n = G$ is such a series, then $A_1$ is characteristic in $G$, and a $\pi$-group or a $\pi'$-group. Hadn't seen this before O_o